# Blender Rendering includes smoke in image render but not in animation render

Tags: rendering, animation, smoke-simulation

Today i open my pc to see my render has failed, there is no smoke in my scene.

I have made the animation and included smoke, the letters are fine but the smoke does not appear in the animation render.
I have rendered the scene with "Render Image" and everything seemed ok? but when i render animation the smoke does not seem to show.

I am sure it has something to do with the render process and i have spent hours researching this to no avail.
You can get the blender file here: https://mega.nz/#!slNTFDKK!ZkCzXKKlv8EtrLOxq1V2glWrp_p0Bbl9-Rk-4UWClTo
Thank you.

Comment: How about when you press F12, does it appear there?

Comment: When I render a still frame of your scene I don't get any smoke. Are you using GPU rendering? If so, maybe try disabling GPU rendering just as a test to see if anything changes. (FYI my system is a Mac, running OS X 10.10 and Blender 2.77)

Comment: Come to think of it, it also may have something to do with the smoke being cached or not. Still testing...

Comment: I reserched it and my Rendering ... thing... is set to CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys i figured it out... and im an idiot.

Turns out the smoke rendering only begins at frame 2.
I never let it go past 1 :/